# How to define an annotation in PDF

Tags: java, annotations, itext

I started working on iText 5.3.2. I want to add annotations to an existing PDF document. I achieved it using the code found here

[image]

Now my concern is how to :

1. set the position of popup being opened on click of the annotation
2. set the font of the popup data
3. set the subject of the annotation
4. set the default state of the popup (open or close) (i used the this constructor but it didn't helped, notice the true,second last arguement)-->`PdfAnnotation.createText(writer, new Rectangle(400,480,420,500), "Title", "Text", true, "Help");`

I have taken the reference from [here](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/)

Answer (score 2):

I've written the book from which you've taken the example, and your question is a tad confusing. I thought you were talking about a popup as described in section 7.4.3 (p229-230), but you're using the code from p220.

Adapting the code from listing 7.28 instead of using the code of listing 7.21 will already help you in the right direction.

1. Set the position of the popup being opened: that's exactly what you do with a Popup annotation.
2. Set the font of the popup data, that's not a property of the Popup annotation but of the parent annotation that is being "popped up". In the case of a Text annotation, you'd do this with Rich Text (not to be confused with RTF). It's very similar to HTML. I don't know if you can define different font families though. I've tried this in Acrobat, and I can only change the font style, not the font family. If you really want to show a different font, you'll need to create your own appearance (see for instance figure 7.13).
3. Set the Subject: this will depend on the type of annotation. I think you're looking for the Title key: /T
4. That's a property of the Popup annotation.

There are many different ways to solve your problem. Please read the book from which you've taken the code. Please don't just copy/paste that code. I've spent a lot of time writing that book, and I'd appreciate it if you mention the source of the material you're posting online.

Comment: Hi @Bruno thanks for the reply and thanks for such a nice book on Itext Library,I edited the question and provided the link from where I took the reference,and regarding the answer I think I have to work more on this to see how your answer can help me

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie: I want to write some annotation in my pdf.  **My Problem is How to super impose two same pdf but having different annotation**